# Java password encryption based on time and string

Tags: java, performance, strings, json

I have a program that:

1. Takes a user specified string
2. Creates password from the string and previous, current, and next day
3. Encrypts the strings
4. Chops some middle characters from the strings (needed to be shorter password)
5. Returns a JSON object with 3 passwords

My main concern is that everything is almost repeated 3 times and there is a lot of string chopping and stitching. **I believe the encryption methods are as short as they will get (not my methods).** Any improvements to shorten the length and run time of the code would be great. Its run time has great importance because it is a REST API.

Controller:

```
public JSONObject getPasswordResults(@RequestParam String searchString) {
    // Final results of previous, current, and next passwords
    String previousResult = "";
    String result = "";
    String nextResult = "";
    try {
        // Previous and next day times, -1 is one day previous, 1 is one day in future
        long previousTime = serviceNowPasswordService.getTime(-1);
        long time = serviceNowPasswordService.getTime(0);
        long nextTime = serviceNowPasswordService.getTime(1);
        // Seeds
        String previousSeed = searchString + previousTime;
        String seed = searchString + time;
        String nextSeed = searchString + nextTime;

        System.out.println("Original: \"" + seed + "\"");

        // Encrypted password calls
        String previousEnc = serviceNowPasswordService.encrypt(previousSeed);
        String enc = serviceNowPasswordService.encrypt(seed);
        String nextEnc = serviceNowPasswordService.encrypt(nextSeed);

        System.out.println("Encrypted: \"" + enc.toUpperCase() + "\"");

        // Chopping passwords to fit length of oracle database requirements
        previousResult = previousEnc.toUpperCase();
        String previous_result_beg = previousResult.substring(0, 8);
        String previous_result_end = previousResult.substring(16, 32);
        previousResult = previous_result_beg + previous_result_end;

        result = enc.toUpperCase();
        String result_beg = result.substring(0, 8);
        String result_end = result.substring(16, 32);
        result = result_beg + result_end;

        nextResult = nextEnc.toUpperCase();
        String next_result_beg = nextResult.substring(0, 8);
        String next_result_end = nextResult.substring(16, 32);
        nextResult = next_result_beg + next_result_end;

        /*
         * Unused for now, maybe needed for future ambitions
         *
        String dec = serviceNowPasswordService.decrypt(enc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: \"" + dec.toUpperCase() + "\"");

        if (dec.equals(original)) {
            System.out.println("Encryption ==> Decryption Successful");
        }
        */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    // Create results as JSON array with object
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("previousPassword", previousResult);
    obj.put("password", result);
    obj.put("nextPassword", nextResult);

    return obj;
}
```

Services:

```
public long getTime(int difference) {

    // Current time
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    time = (time / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    time += difference;

    return time;
}

public String encrypt(String searchString) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String hexKey = "GD6GTT56HKY4HGF6FH3JG9J5";
    //TripleDes3 encryptor = new TripleDes3(new String(Hex.decodeHex(hexKey.toCharArray())));
    try {
        TripleDes3(hexKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    bytes = searchString.getBytes("ISO8859_15");
    bytes = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, ((bytes.length + 7) / 8) * 8);
    return new String(Hex.encodeHex(encryptB(bytes)));
}

public void TripleDes3(String encryptionKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, DecoderException {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
    try {
        key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("ISO8859_15"), "DESede");
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("0123456789abcdef".toCharArray()));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte[] encryptB(byte[] bytes) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Key) key, iv);
    return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the repetition you already noticed by extracting the process into a separate method.

In the end your method might look like:

```
public JSONObject getPasswordResults(@RequestParam String searchString) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("previousPassword", encryptWithTime(searchString, serviceNowPasswordService.getTime(-1)));
    obj.put("password", encryptWithTime(searchString, serviceNowPasswordService.getTime(0)));
    obj.put("nextPassword", encryptWithTime(searchString, serviceNowPasswordService.getTime(1)));
    return obj;
}
```

That's the simple-ish part. To make this work you need to extract the steps of you method into `encryptWithTime`:

```
public String encryptWithTime(String cleartext, long time) {
    try {
        String cryptext = serviceNowPasswordService.encrypt(cleartext + time).toUpperCase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return cryptext.substring(0,8) + cryptext.substring(16,32);
}
```

This is **extremely dense** code, information-wise. I removed a significant number of your intermediate variables. This may be unwise overall, because there is a lot going on at once in there.
This makes processing the code mentally a lot more challenging.

Comment: I like that, I don't mind the denseness, thats what commenting is for.

Comment: This may be a bit extreme, but I still think that if the code *NEEDS* a comment, it is either very complicated code or it has to be written differently. Otherwise, let the code speak for itself. For instance, is the `// Seeds` comment really necessary if variables are called `previousSeed`, `seed` and `nextSeed`?

Comment: @ChatterOne why not take that, take the other points you seem to have and write an answer with those?

Comment: @Vogel612 Because your answer looks good enough to me. I was just replying to theblindprophet and that was the only point that I had.

Comment: @ChatterOne there's nothing wrong with multiple answers on one question. I'm looking forward to your review :)